# HighCharts onclick this.point.name is undefined

Tags: jquery, highcharts

I'm wanting to add an onclick listener to a HighCharts Pie graph.
The pie graph work and so does the onnclick.
I am returning the data for the chart with a php script returning json data.

The problem that I have is that while I can return the "this.x" and "this.y" values as well as the "this.series.name", I am unable to return the "this.point.name" value. When ever I try, I can see in firebug that an error is generated for "this.point" being undefined. An example of this problem would be if I attached a Jquery alert to the click event handler, and used "this.y" , I would get back the same value I am using for my tooltip. But If I try "this.point.name" , it fails. Below you can see my example. You can see that for the tooltip and the dataLabels, this value works, just not for the series point event. Any ideas?

Here is the the code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var options = {
        chart: {
            renderTo: 'pie_main',
            plotBackgroundColor: null,
            plotBorderWidth: null,
            plotShadow: false
        },
        title: {
            text: 'Values by Type'
        },
        tooltip: {
            formatter: function() {
                return '<b>'+ this.point.name +'</b>: '+ this.y;
            }
        },
        plotOptions: {
            pie: {
                allowPointSelect: true,
                cursor: 'pointer',
                dataLabels: {
                    enabled: true,
                    color: '#000000',
                    connectorColor: '#000000',
                    formatter: function() {
                        return '<b>'+ this.point.name +'</b>: '+ this.y;
                    }
                }
            },
            series: {
                point: {
                    events: {
                        click: function () {
                            alert(this.point.name);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        },
        series: [{
            type: 'pie',
            name: 'Browser share',
            data: []
        }]
    }

    $.getJSON("../php/get_pie_cnts.php", function(json) {
        options.series[0].data = json;
        chart = new Highcharts.Chart(options);
    });

});
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For the point click event you are looking for `this.name`, because `this` refers to the Point object on which the click was performed, as defined in [the API](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#plotOptions.series.point.events.click).

In the two formatters functions `this` has a very specific set of data available. It gives access to, among others, `this.point` and `this.series`, as defined in [the API](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#plotOptions.pie.dataLabels.formatter).

See [this JSFiddle demonstration](http://jsfiddle.net/4hsj37md/) of all three in use.

Comment: Thanks!! This is exactly what I was trying to accomplish. Thank you for not only explaining, but linking the API location. I had been searching through it and could not find this.